# How do I assign weights using Kernel function based on a vector of pairwise Euclidean distance?

Tags: r, machine-learning, euclidean-distance, kernel-density

I want to quantify the dissimilarity between two group. Each group has 5 observations, so there are 25 combinations.

For each combination, I have calculated their pairwise Euclidean distance (based on feature space). So I have had a vector of pairwise Euclidean distances as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
runif(n=25, min=50, max=90)
 [1] 60.62035 64.88496 72.91413 86.32831 58.06728 85.93559 87.78701 76.43191 75.16456 52.47145 58.23898 57.06227 77.48091
[14] 65.36415 80.79366 69.90797 78.70474 89.67624 65.20141 81.09781 87.38821 58.48570 76.06695 55.02220 60.68883
```

I want to use Kernel function to assign weights to the 25 combinations based on the vector of pairwise Euclidean distances. Shorter distance, larger weight.

How can I do it in R?

I have limited knowledge about kernel. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

I would really appreciated it even if you can give me some hints about the mathematical formula without any programming.

Comment: Idk if it will work for you application, but what about something like: ```weight <- max(distance) - distance```?

Comment: @AdamB. Thanks, it is a straightforward way. But I want to use Kernel to assign weights. I'm just wondering what formular or R function that I can use.